# Referenced Project Not Included in Azure Remote Build

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy the FunctionApp from https://github.com/anthonychu/functions-puppeteer-sharp-razor to Azure using Azure Functions Core Tools but I get the following error: Skipping project "/tmp/zipdeploy/RazorPagesApp/RazorPagesApp.csproj" because it was not found.

The RazorPagesApp is a referenced project which isn't being picked up by the remote build. The FunctionApp builds successfully locally. Any ideas as to how to include a referenced project for remote builds?

Comment: Are you even referencing any of the projects types in the parent project? Try deploying self contained as well

Comment: When you are using C# or Java, then azure function host doesn't care the source code, the key is the compiled files. Just like .dll or .class. You can use zip deploy to deploy the function compiled files witch included other project.

Comment: I have post an answer, you can have a look. It will tells you how to do when you need to deploy referenced project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a project that depends on another project, you only need to compile the main project and go to the compiled folder to pack the compressed file. The following is the general method:

1, First, put your two project under the same folder and then build your function app. (This step will compiled the two project code to one folder.)

2, Go to the bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 in your function app. Compress all files in this folder.(RazorPagesApp will be compiled to this place.)

[image]

3, Use command to upload the compiled code.

For example, on my side the command is:

`az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group 20201014bowman --name 1014bowmanlinux --src C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FunctionApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\netcoreapp3.1.zip`

On my side, I can deploy success.

This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-zip-file-with-azure-cli

The general method for deploying reference projects is as shown above.(For C# and Java languages, the Azure Function host does not pay attention to the source code, it only pays attention to the compiled files. Such as .dll and .class.)

By the way, I saw the Puppeteer used in the code. This means simple azure function sandbox doesn't supported it. You can have a look of this blog:

https://www.hardkoded.com/blog/running-puppeteer-sharp-azure-functions

Above Blog will tells you how to use Puppeteer-Sharp on azure function.